# Where is temporary folder in IsolatedStorage (Windows Phone)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I can not find where is temporary folder to add temp file into.
How do i find?

Answer (score 1):

You just create your own folder and manage the content:

```cs
private void SaveTempFile(string fileName, object data)
{
    var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    if (storage.DirectoryExists("temp") == false) 
        storage.CreateDirectory("temp");

    fileName = Path.Combine("temp", fileName);
    using (var fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, storage))
    {
       //Write the data
       using (var isoFileWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
       {
            // write your data in the format of your choice
        }
    }
}
```

Delete the file whenever you want to

```cs
public void DeleteTempFile(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (storage.DirectoryExists("temp") == false) return;

        fileName = Path.Combine("temp", fileName);
        if (storage.FileExists(fileName))
        {
            storage.DeleteFile(fileName);
        }
     }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no that kind of folder prepared for app on Windows Phone. You have to create it on your own and manage clearing the content form there when it's no longer needed. However you don't need to bother about deleting that files when your app is uninstalled - whole application folder is deleted from isolated storage then.